# BASH Making pileup files recursively using values piped from one column in another file

Tags: linux, bash, loops, awk, samtools

I'm trying to make pileup files using `samtools` from two files, File1 and File2.

I have split up File1 and File2 by chromosome, resulting in having 44 files named following the format:

```
chr${c}.${TISSUE}_run1_en2hic_PE1.bam.sorted.bam.breaks_COL1_and_COL2_ONLY
```

where ${c} is a number between 1 and 22, and $TISSUE is either colon or muscle--22 chromosomes for colon, and 22 for muscle. I.e.; chr1.colon_run1_en2hic_PE1.bam.sorted.bam.breaks_COL1_and_COL2_ONLY
    chr2.colon_run1_en2hic_PE1.bam.sorted.bam.breaks_COL1_and_COL2_ONLY

```
.
.
.

chr22.colon_run1_en2hic_PE1.bam.sorted.bam.breaks_COL1_and_COL2_ONLY
chr1.muscle_run1_en2hic_PE1.bam.sorted.bam.breaks_COL1_and_COL2_ONLY
.
.
.
```

These files consist of two columns, the first just shows the chromosome number, and the second column is a position on that chromosome. I.e.;

```
head chr2.colon_run1_en2hic_PE1.bam.sorted.bam.breaks_COL1_and_COL2_ONLY 
chr2 103977
chr2 112051
chr2 126199
chr2 146288
chr2 147797
chr2 147822
chr2 148548
chr2 148525
chr2 158189
chr2 158188
```

For each row in the file (for example, `"chr2.colon_run1_en2hic_PE1.bam.sorted.bam.breaks_COL1_and_COL2_ONLY"`), I need to take the position, call it 'x', from column 2, and use it to get a range of `a-b`, where `a=x-5` and `b=x+5`. I'll then plug those values into the following script:

```
samtools mpileup -f [REFERENCE GENOME] File1 File2 -r chr${c}:a-b
```

For example, suppose I'm looking at chromosome 2, position 103977 (row 1 above). Then my script would be

```
samtools mpileup -f [REFERENCE GENOME] File1 File2 -r chr2:103972-103982
```

So basically, it's a loop within a loop within a loop. Something like,

```
for t in $(colon, muscle)
do
  for c in $seq (1 22)
  do
    for item (or maybe row?) in 
      chr${c}.${t}_run1_en2hic_PE1.bam.sorted.bam.breaks_COL1_and_COL2_ONLY
    do
      awk '{print $2}' | something something something 
      x= position in col 2, a=x-5 b=x+5
      samtools mpileup -f [REFERENCE GENOME] File1 File2 -r chr${c}:a-b
    done 
  done
done
...
```

Thanks in advance. I'm brand new to working with Linux and I have essentially no computer science training.

Comment: Hi, please use edit and use the Code(curly brackets) feature on the post editor for readability.
The question is unreadable, please organize it.
I recommend you to look on other questions to learn how to write a proper question.
GL :)

Answer (score 1):

Awk processes a line at a time, so I'd go for something like

```
for t in colon muscle; do
    for c in $(seq 1 22); do
        awk '{ print $2-5 "-" $2+5 }' chr${c}.${t}_run1_en2hic_PE1.bam.sorted.bam.breaks_COL1_and_COL2_ONLY |
        while read -r range; do
            samtools mpileup -f [REFERENCE GENOME] File1 File2 -r chr${c}:$range
        done 
    done
done
```

In other words, Awk processes the whole file and feeds one line of output at a time to the final `while read -r range` loop.

I don't understand how you split these files in the first place, or what a pileup is, but I suspect this could be simplified considerably if you just worked directly on `File1` and `File2` instead.

You could probably also avoid the outer loops and just run Awk on all the `*_ONLY` files directly. You can get the current file name from Awk's internal variable `FILENAME` but in this case you can apparently just use the first field.

```
awk '{ print $1 ":" $2-5 "-" $2+5 }' *_ONLY |
while read -r chrrange; do
    samtools mpileup -f [REFERENCE GENOME] File1 File2 -r "$chrrange"
done
```

If you can't use `$1` directly, try `split(FILENAME, f, /\./)` and print `f[1]` to get the chromosome identifier part from the filename.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
module load SAMtools

awk '{print $1, $2-5 "-" $2+5}' FILE PATH |\
while read chrom range
do

    samtools mpileup -f /REFERENCE GENOME\
            /${chrom}.COLON BAM FILE\
            /${chrom}.MUSCLE BAM FILE\
            -r $chrom:$range -o ${chrom}.colon.${range}.pileup
```

`done`

Thank you for your help!